# Using custom fonts on shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I would like to use a custom font in my shiny app (on plots) on shinyapps.io. I have my Roboto-Regular.ttf in the `./www/` directory. And this is the upper portion of my app.R file:

```
dir.create('~/.fonts')
system("chmod +x ./www/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
system("cp ./www/Roboto-Regular.ttf ~/.fonts/")
system('fc-cache -f -v ~/.fonts/')
system('fc-match Roboto')

library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern="Roboto",prompt=FALSE)
loadfonts()
print(fonts())
```

Upon deploying the app, I end up with an error that looks like this:

```
Registering fonts with R
Scanning ttf files in /usr/share/fonts/, ~/.fonts/ ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
/home/shiny/.fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttfWarning in gzfile(dest, "w") :
  cannot open compressed file '/opt/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library/extrafontdb/metrics/Roboto-Regular.afm.gz', probable reason 'Permission denied'
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : cannot open the connection
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Does anyone see what might be wrong?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Did you figure it out meanwhile?

Comment: I have added the reply I got from RStudio regarding this. If it works, let me know and I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a bit of struggle I found an even simpler solution that works on `shinyapps.io`:

Here we go:

1. Place custom font in `www` directory: e.g. `IndieFlower.ttf` from [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Indie+Flower)
2. Follow the steps from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/0czcsM4vziM)

This leads to the following upper part of the  `app.R` file:

```
dir.create('~/.fonts')
file.copy("www/IndieFlower.ttf", "~/.fonts")
system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')
```

Since Linux looks into the `.fonts` directory to search fonts, you don't need the `extrafont` package, but you can directly use those fonts like:

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=seq(1,10,.1), y=seq(1,10,.1))) +
      geom_line(position="jitter", color="red", size=2) + theme_bw() +
      theme(text=element_text(size = 16, family = "IndieFlower"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. This was a required step in order for me to draw a treemap with Japanese labels, as the treemap() function didn't seem to find an appropriate font to render Japanese characters.

Comment: this solution work for me in 2021

Comment: works like charm. Nice and simple, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer I received from RStudio regarding this. I haven't tested this out myself.

Hi,

Our developer was able to advise this is due to a possibly unfortunate design choice made when they created **extrafont** and the associated **extrafontdb** package. The extrafont font database is stored in the **extrafontdb** package directory -- that's essentially all that the **extrafontdb** package is used for.

This means that the **extrafontdb** directory needs to be user-writable. If the user installs the package, this will work fine, but if root installs the package (as is the case on **shinyapps.io**), then it won't work.

One potential workaround is to install the **extrafontdb** package to library that is in subdirectory of the app.

To do it: create an `r-lib/` subdir, and download the **extrafontdb** source package there:

```
dir.create('r-lib')
download.file('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/extrafontdb_1.0.tar.gz','r-lib/extrafontdb_1.0.tar.gz')
```

When deployed, the app will include this `r-lib/` subdirectory and the **extrafontdb** source package.

Then, at the top of the app, install the **extrafontdb** package from the source package, into the `r-lib` directory.

```
.libPaths(c('r-lib', .libPaths()))
install.packages('r-lib/extrafontdb_1.0.tar.gz',type = 'source',repos = NULL)
```

They deployed an app on **shinyapps.io** that does the **extrafontdb** installation, and it works fine. The libpath is set so so that `install.packages()` will install from the provided source package to the `r-lib/` subdirectory of the app.

Please let us know if you're able to implement the above or have any additional questions.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I think I got closer.. But it it still doesn't work for me. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100069/ggplot-with-customized-font-not-showing-properly-on-shinyapps-io)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an alternative answer to [symbolrush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812219/using-custom-fonts-on-shinyapps-io/55159245#55159245) which I found did not work. Here was the code I used initially:

```
# Add fonts to shiny linux server
if (Sys.info()[['sysname']] == 'Linux') {
    dir.create('~/.fonts')
fonts = c(
    "www/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf",
    "www/IBMPlexSans-Bold.ttf",
    "www/IBMPlexSans-Medium.ttf"
    )
file.copy(fonts, "~/.fonts")
system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')
}

# Load fonts and set theme
font_paths("fonts")

font_add("IBMPlexSans", regular = "IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf")
font_add("IBMPlexSans-Bold", regular = "IBMPlexSans-Bold.ttf")
font_add("IBMPlexSans-Medium", regular = "IBMPlexSans-Medium.ttf")
showtext_auto()
```

The bizarre thing is that the first instance of the app on shinyapps.io worked, including the custom fonts. However when the app went to sleep and was opened a second time, I get this error in the log:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : font file not found for 'regular' type
```

I was never able to debug why this was the case, but I tried a simpler solution that has worked perfectly so far. I moved my fonts to a `/font` folder in the app folder (I don't think using the `/www` folder is necessary) and added the /font folder using `path_folder()`:

```
library(showtext)
# Load fonts and set theme
font_paths("fonts")

font_add("IBMPlexSans", regular = "IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf")
font_add("IBMPlexSans-Bold", regular = "IBMPlexSans-Bold.ttf")
font_add("IBMPlexSans-Medium", regular = "IBMPlexSans-Medium.ttf")
showtext_auto()
```

I hope this helps anyone who is having problems with their app not running after the first instance, as I could not find the same situation anywhere on stackoverflow.