# Using google fonts in R on windows 10

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-fonts

*I want to (and used to) use custom fonts with ggplot on Windows, Mac and Linus (shinyapps.io, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812219/using-custom-fonts-on-shinyapps-io/55159245#55159245)). This is a while ago and - somehow - doesn't work anymore..*

---

What I tried in detail:

Step 1: Initial font availability..

```
windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"
```

Step 2: Add a Google Font

```
sysfonts::font_add_google("Permanent Marker")
```

Step 3: Make sure the font is registered.

```
sysfonts::font_families()
[1] "sans"             "serif"            "mono"             "Permanent Marker"

windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"
```

**Why does `sysfonts` see and show the custom font whereas `windowsFonts` doesn't?**

Step 4: Try to use the custom font in a plot:

Using `serif` works:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "serif"))
```

[image]

Using `Permanent Marker` doesn't:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Permanent Marker"))
```

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 2):

One way is through the `showtext` package. The procedure is described in detail [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html) and [there](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-008/RJ-2015-008.pdf).

Basically, we need to use `showtext_auto()` so that the `sysfonts` fonts are available to `ggplot`.

---

A minimal example:

```
# initial configuration
windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"

# load new font
sysfonts::font_add_google("Permanent Marker")
sysfonts::font_families()
[1] "sans"             "serif"            "mono"            
[4] "Permanent Marker"

# use it
showtext_auto()
ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) + 
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Permanent Marker"))
```

[image]